# javafx tableview empty table

Tags: javafx, tableview

I have a piece of code to create data for `TableView`. It should not have errors or some problems. But `TableView` doesn't show data. In debug mode `TableView` has the correct data. I cannot resolve this problem. Thanks for your help.

**Controller:**

```
public class ServersController {
@FXML
TableView<SQLServerProp> table;
@FXML
TableColumn<SQLServerProp, String> colSNum;
@FXML
TableColumn<SQLServerProp, String> colSpec;
@FXML
TableColumn<SQLServerProp, Integer> colCpu;
@FXML
TableColumn<SQLServerProp, Double> colMem;
public PostgreSQLJDBC PSQL;

public void setPSQL(PostgreSQLJDBC PSQL) {
    this.PSQL = PSQL;
}
public ServersController()
{
    table = new TableView<SQLServerProp>();
    colCpu = new TableColumn<SQLServerProp, Integer>("cpu");
    colSpec = new TableColumn<SQLServerProp, String>("specific");
    colMem = new TableColumn<SQLServerProp, Double>("memory");
    colSNum = new TableColumn<SQLServerProp, String>("snumber");
}

public void LoadData()
{
    List<SQLServerProp> dataServers = PSQL.GetDataServers();
    colSNum.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SQLServerProp, String>("snumber"));
    colSpec.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SQLServerProp, String>("specific"));
    colCpu.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SQLServerProp, Integer>("cpu"));
    colMem.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SQLServerProp, Double>("memory"));

    ObservableList<SQLServerProp> dataServersO = FXCollections.observableArrayList(dataServers);
    table.setItems(dataServersO);
    table.getColumns().addAll(colSNum, colSpec, colCpu, colMem);
}
```

**Model** (getter and setter only for snumber (for example), other fields have analogy getters and setters):

```
public class SQLServerProp {
public final SimpleStringProperty snumber;
public final SimpleStringProperty specific;
public final SimpleDoubleProperty memory;
public final SimpleIntegerProperty cpu;


public SQLServerProp(String sNumber, String specific, Double memory, Integer cpu) {
    this.snumber = new SimpleStringProperty(sNumber);
    this.specific = new SimpleStringProperty(specific);
    this.memory = new SimpleDoubleProperty(memory);
    this.cpu = new SimpleIntegerProperty(cpu);
}


public String getSnumber() {
    return snumber.get();
}

public StringProperty snumberProperty() {
    return snumber;
}

public void setSnumber(String snumber) {
    this.snumber.set(snumber);
}
```

**XML for Window** with `TableView:`

```
    <AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="438.0" prefWidth="596.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.131" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="ptk.controller.ServersController">
   <children>
      <TableView layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="418.0" prefWidth="466.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="116.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="10.0">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="colSNum" prefWidth="94.0" text="Serial Number" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="colSpec" prefWidth="237.0" text="Specification" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="colCpu" prefWidth="59.0" text="CPU, kernel" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="colMem" prefWidth="79.0" text="Memory, Gb" />
        </columns>
      </TableView>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: See linked question - you are re-creating the table and columns, so you are adding data to controls that are never shown. Note that you are also missing the `fx:id` attribute in your `TableView` in the FXML file.

Comment: @sillyfly Thanks! Its work fine!